# Method find in ReactiveMongo is deprecated. Use 'find' with optional projection

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am working on a project which integrates play framework with
 reactive mongo. I recently upgraded reactive mongo to 0.18.5 version.
 After upgrading i get the warning:

```
method find in trait GenericCollection is deprecated (since 0.16.0): Use find with optional `projection`
```

Although the code compiles and works just fine with this warning but i would like to know how to eliminate this warning completely.

I tried adding projection field to the find method as :

```
 .find(
       Json.obj(
         "cid" -> cid,
         "out"-> out,
         "isDone" -> false,
         "numberOfAttempts" -> Json.obj("$lte" -> 3),
         "isActive" -> true
       ),projection=Option.empty
```

But this gives the following error:

```
 both object BSONDocumentWrites in trait ImplicitBSONHandlers of type reactivemongo.play.json.package.BSONDocumentWrites.type and object JsObjectDocumentWriter in trait ImplicitBSONHandlers of type and  reactivemongo.play.json.package.JsObjectDocumentWriter.type
 match expected type play.api.libs.json.OWrites[J]
```

Here are the version of libraries i am using:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.18.5-play27"
```

Can anyone guide me as to how to remove this warning and properly work with projections. I know that projection is used to return a specific field from the query result but in my case i am trying to return an entire object. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The latest version is 0.18.6

Comment: Same warning comes even if i use 0.18.6

Comment: Never said it removes the warning, but that for an upgrade the latest version is 0.18.6, not 0.18.5

Comment: Thanks. I made the necessary changes in my build.sbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Option.empty[JsObject]` to remove type ambiguity for the projection (or use silencer to ignore this warning).